# Floors squeak a lot since installing new carpet

Tags: subfloor, carpet, squeak

Our condo was built in 1989, and I moved in in 2005 with all new carpets. A few months ago (15 years later!), we had new wall-to-wall carpet installed. Now there's creaks and squeaks everywhere in the sub floor where there used to be only minimal or none. Even in the kitchen where we didn't have carpet in the past. Seems so strange. I think the carpet looks correctly installed, and we have good quality padding and carpet. Did removing the tension from the previous carpet cause the change? Is the solution to just use one of those tools that screws the sub floor to the joist through the carpet?

Comment: You haven't yet proved that the subflooring is the source of the noise.  Perhaps the source is the new carpet padding layer itself, for example.  I would give it 6 months to "settle in" before taking action.  Or, pull up the carpet and see if walking on the subfloor directly does cause squeaking.

Comment: The carpet itself could have had a thicker backing or the pad or both and a combination of not stretched as tight thinker backer less dense padding . Yes you said quality pad but a softer pad may be part of the problem.

Comment: Thanks....Looks like we have a little more due diligence we need to solve for. Appreciate it!

Comment: Is it possible that when pulling up old carpet and/or removing the tack strips and such could loosen nails in the floorboards causing creaks? The sounds seem to refer to the walls near the baseboards.